# Filter Link Tracking issue in Adobe DTM

Tags: javascript, jquery, tags, analytics, adobe-analytics

I am facing issue with adobe image request in network tab, I can proper see results in console, but while in image request I am not seeing Evar55 current value.
Actually there is bug Analytics tracking issue- Evar55

Evar55 should capture the value of filter selected by users on search result page and PLP.

So now the next thing I have written the code, which is working absolutely fine in Console, and I can see the result but in network tab the image request is giving previous value not giving the current value of facet.

Here I am sharing the screenshot and code with you, please tell what issue is.

In DTM, I have created page load rule – conditions trigger rule at DOM ready –then adobe analytics open editor I have pasted this code

---

Code

```
var oldXHR = window.XMLHttpRequest;

function newXHR() {
    var realXHR = new oldXHR();
realXHR.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
if(realXHR.readyState==4 && realXHR.status==200){
           //run your code here
window.setTimeout(function() {
if(s.pageName && (s.pageName.indexOf('plp:')>-1 || s.pageName.indexOf('search')>-1)){
var PFF = document.getElementsByClassName('selected-categories')[0].innerText;
PFF_Final = PFF.replace(/ /g, '').replace(/:/g, '|');

if(PFF_Final.indexOf('Categories|')>-1 || PFF_Final.indexOf('search|')>-1){
console.log('N/A');
}
else if(PFF_Final && typeof PFF_Final !== 'undefined' && PFF !== 'null' && PFF !== ''){
//PFF_Final = PFF.replace(/ /g, '').replace(/:/g, '|');

   s.linkTrackVars = 'eVar91';
   s.eVar91 =  PFF_Final.trim();
//s.tl(this, 'o');
console.log(PFF_Final);
}

}
},1500);
        }
    }, false);
    return realXHR;
}
window.XMLHttpRequest = newXHR;
```

Note : - I have change the Evar55 to Evar91 because Evar 55 which is already in use.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnn1T.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJ1M6.png)

Thanks, 
Payal

Answer (score 1):

At face value, the immediate reason the code you posted  does not make a request because you have the `s.tl` call commented out...

Second, a note: if you are filtering for image requests in the network tab, you will almost certainly not see the Adobe Analytics (AA) request there, because unless you are using a very ancient browser or else have javascript turned off and using the `<img>` tag method, it will show up as either a javascript request or ajax (xhr) request (depending on what version of the AA library and how long the request is).

If you are still not seeing the request, there are a couple additional things to try. One or more of these may or may not be true/necessary, depending on what version of the AA library you are using:

1) When you pass `this` as the first argument, it must be a valid anchor element  with an `href` attribute `<a href='..'></a>`. Since this is not applicable within the context of your posted code, try changing the first argument to boolean `true`.

2) Add a 3rd argument to the `s.tl` call. This argument is supposed to be a description for the link click, e.g. `s.tl(true,'o','some link');` It can be anything you want; it's what shows up in the native link reports in AA (that you will almost certainly ignore, in favor of looking at that `eVar91` report, instead). All versions of the AA library require this 3rd argument if you want to track it as a click/interaction server call. Without it, in more recent versions of AA, it will trigger the request as a page view call, but in older versions of the AA library, it will not trigger a call at all.

3) Again, depending on your AA lib version, it will not include anything above `eVar75`. I don't remember the exact AA version where `eVar76+` was introduced *(edit: Looks like Starting [AM1.4](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/sc/appmeasurement/release/c_release_notes_mjs.html). Legacy H code not supported)*. As a quick check, try using `eVar75` or lower to see if it shows up in the request. Note: I'm only putting this for completeness sake, but I don't think this your issue, since it seems from your post you may have tried with `eVar55` already? But may as well be certain.  If this is the case, I would suggest updating to the latest AppMeasurement library.  If for some reason you are unable to do that, and still need to use `eVar91`, then the alternative is to pop it as a `contextData` variable, e.g. `s.contextData['eVar91']='foo';` and then map it to the real `eVar91` in a Processing Rule within the AA interface.  If your AA library is old enough that even `contextData` variables don't work (H23.2 or lower).. then I suggest you make it your highest priority in life to upgrade to a more recent version of the AA lib..

If after all of this you still do not see an AA call, just type `s.t(true,'o','foo');` into the js console. Do you see an http request? If you *do not* see a request, then you have some deeper issue not directly related to the posted code. Perhaps your AA library is not present, or it is not loaded before this is triggered, or is under a different namespace than the default `s` namespace. But it's not really feasible to write lots of random guesses here vs. looking at the site.

If you *do* see a request, then my best guess at this point is you having a timing issue. Perhaps there is a page (re)load happening and it is not getting a chance to trigger? But again, it's not very feasible to speculate on a site unseen.

Comment: Hi @Crayon, I did the same thing, but still i am not seeing result in network tab.

Comment: Hi @crayon. Can you please help me on that filter link issue.. it's very critical.actually I posted in a new way which is correct.this one is not related to my code. So I will delete this..pls pls give me reply on my today's filter link question.i am not able to mapped evar.

Comment: @PayalDaryani if it is critical then perhaps you should consider hiring someone to do it for you?

Comment: Hi @crayon, but apologies for that,I didn't meant like that. Critical may be the wrong word I have chosen.once again apologies.but really I need from yours.